# How to move subfolder with files to another directory?

Tags: php, file, scandir

I use this code to move files from one folder to another.

```
$src = path_a;
$dest = path_b;
// get files
$files = scandir($src);
// movin files
foreach ($files as $file){
    if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
    if (copy($src.$file, $dest.$file)){
        $delete[] = $src.$file;
    }
}
// del files
foreach ($delete as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

It works, but i have one subfolder with some files in source foulder ("path_a").
How i can move this subfolder with files to "path_b" and delete path_a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
foreach ($files as $file){
    if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
    rename($src.$file, $dest.file);
}
```

For more details, have a look to [rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php).